# Get the value from file using Nested while loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, file

I have the PHP code as below:

```
$file1 = 'file1.txt';
$file2 = 'file2.txt';
$files1 = fopen($file1,'r');
$files2 = fopen($file2,'r');
$title = "";    
while(!feof($files1)){
$data1 = explode(';', fgets($files1));
    while(!feof($files2)){
        $data2 = explode(';', fgets($files2));      

    }
    //I want to output $data2[0] in here
    //and want to make the calculation between $data1[0] - $data2[0]
    // The problem is that I can not use the $data1[0] outside the while loop of file2 that make me can not calculation.

}
```

The problem as I comment in the code.Anyone know help me please,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file1 = 'file1.txt';
$file2 = 'file2.txt';
$files1 = fopen($file1,'r');
$files2 = fopen($file2,'r');
$title = "";    
while(!feof($files1)){
$data1 = explode(';', fgets($files1));
    while(!feof($files2)){
        $data2 = explode(';', fgets($files2));      
        $data2Array[]=$data2;
    }

     // You can use $data2Array[0] here now

    //I want to output $data2[0] in here
    //and want to make the calculation between $data1[0] - $data2[0]
    // The problem is that I can not use the $data1[0] outside the while loop of file2 that make me can not calculation.

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer so much, but when I output it show me the `ArrayArray`

Comment: Yes $data2Array will be an array of Arrays with $data2 elements. so try this print_r($data2Array) you will then get the structure. You can echo like echo $data2Array[0][0]

Answer (score 0):

Because the while loops are nested, you can still use `$data1` within the while loop where you create `$data2`, because that is also within the while loop where you define `$data1`